# rspec find_by_id and wrong number of arguments(0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Somehow I cannot figure out why my request spec fails due to error:

Wrong number of arguments(0 for 1)

when I use find_by_id in show method.

This is my show method

```
def show
  @message = Message.find_by_id(params[:id])

  # rest of code
end
```

This is my request spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "message pages" do
  subject { page }

  before do
    @message = FactoryGirl.create(:message)
  end

  it "should show message page properly" do
    visit message_path(@message.id)
    page.should have_content(@message.content) # this fails as message path ends up with wrong number of arguments error
  end
end
```

If I change find_by_id() to find() then everything works okay. I need find_by_id because I do not want to raise 404 error instead I want to check if nil then direct user to appropriate page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "find_by_id" (which by the way is deprecated...) you can just use `find` and rescue from the exception. This is much simpler.

```
def show
  begin
    @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::NotFound
    do whatever you want on missing message
    return
  end
  # rest of code
end
```

Answer (score 2):

can you try either:

```
visit message_path(@message)
```

or

```
visit message_path(id: @message.id)
```

and report back

Comment: Also visit message_path(id: @message.to_param)